# sortable.js ( No jQuery ) doesn't work in IE with touch screen

Tags: internet-explorer, touch, jquery-ui-sortable, drag

I am using this library for sorting items: http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/
In Chrome everything's fine, but in IE 11 dragging is not working when I use the touch screen of my PC.

I guess the problem is in pointer events for IE 11.  Has anyone found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's more a workaround like a solution but maybe you try

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

it helps me to make Fullcalendar touchable so mabye it works with sortable too.

Comment: Thanks, Felix, but I'm not using JQueryUI